# Is it possible to have a dynamic chart type in shiny? (Type of output changes based on input)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, rendering, shiny-reactivity

I want the chart to appear in the *same location* *in the UI* but the type of chart output depends on what the user selects. The example doesn't work but might explain what I'm looking for.

**Simple Example**

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Title"),

    # Sidebar 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("time", "Select time frame", choices = c("Hour", "Minute", "Day", "Month"), selected = "Day")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           uiOutput("plot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$plot = renderUI({
        if(input$time %in% c("Hour", "Minute")){
            renderPlot(mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(disp, mpg )) + geom_point())
        }
        else if(input$time %in% c("Day", "Month")){
            renderPlotly(mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(disp, mpg )) + geom_point())
        }
    })
   
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Please let me know if something like this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could suffice. You can have the renderUI conditionally switch a plotOutput so it shows in the same area. Using the bulk of your code, I changed the if statements to have a plot/plotly output instead of the render plot/plotly. Then I have a separate render plot/plotly output for each of these new plots, which I labeled plot1/2

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Title"),
  
  # Sidebar 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("time", "Select time frame", choices = c("Hour", "Minute", "Day", "Month"), selected = "Day")
    ),
    
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server 
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot = renderUI({
    if(input$time %in% c("Hour", "Minute")){
        plotOutput("plot1")
    } else if(input$time %in% c("Day", "Month")){
        plotlyOutput("plot2")
    }
  })
  
  output$plot1<-renderPlot({
    mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(disp, mpg )) + geom_point()
  })
  
  output$plot2<-renderPlotly({
    mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(disp, mpg )) + geom_point()
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this works! Best of luck!

Comment: That works great! Thanks!